# Seamless Buffered Memory - Disc Data Object Thingy

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, buffer, disk

Sorry this should be a google question but im just getting pages of results about hard drives etc!

is there such a thingy for javascript / node.js that will allow a large data collection to be accessed in memory but automatically buffered off to disc file as and when required?

i.e if you try to access index outside in memory collection it will just pull from disc and update the buffer.